# Desktop shortcut for rebooting into different OS

Tags: windows, ssd, multi-boot

I currently have Windows 10 installed on an SSD. There is another HDD in the machine for storage purposes. I wanted to add another SSD and install another OS (maybe Windows 7). I know I can always choose during the boot process as to which OS to run. However, is it possible to have a shortcut (for any batch file or something) on the desktop of each of the OS to directly reboot into the other OS?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes (at least to my understanding), but involves a bit of hassle in order to accomplish dual booting from the desktop. You would be correct in assuming that you would need a type of batch script in order to run or trigger the process to dual boot from your desktop.

**Note that this information applies to XP and Windows Visita but the concept could be applied to later versions of Windows.**

You will need to preform the following:

Create the Shortcut to Reboot into XP:

```
bcdedit /bootsequence {ntldr} /addfirst
Shutdown /r /t 0
```

The first line runs the bcdedit tool and sets the XP partition as a one-time boot default, and then the second line calls the shutdown command with the reboot option.

Once you are done, save the batch file into a folder, making sure to name the file with the .bat extension and choose All Files in the “Save as type” drop-down (very important).

You can also give the shortcut a fun icon if you want, or not. Either way, you’ll now have a shortcut that will reboot you into XP by clicking on it (and clicking through the UAC prompt if you have UAC enabled).

For extra credit you can also create a shortcut that doesn’t prompt for UAC, but it takes a few more steps to create.

Here is the [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-shortcuts-to-quickly-reboot-to-the-alternate-os-in-a-vistaxp-dual-boot/) for a full guide on how to perform the setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will give it a go :) Hopefully it will work in Win 7 & 10.

Comment: I'm not sure if that ID works for later versions of Windows. I would replace it with the "resume object" ID for both batches. The line being otherwise the same. (check the full guide)

Comment: Also, note that the "Shutdown /r" is supposed to be on a new line for it to be recognized. (and the "/t 0" part is pointless)

Comment: @1N07 "the "/t 0" part is pointless" I wouldn't say it's pointless, it makes it shutdown NOW, instead of waiting ~30 seconds (which is the default)

Comment: @Techie007 Right you are... I forgot there's a wait time by default.