# How can I quickly boot into a secondary drive without changing the default startup drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot

Basically what I want to do is have 2 different hard drives and 2 different windows 10 installations on my computer. I want to have a default, which the computer automatically boots to every time I restart, and another that I can switch to on my command during startup.. to keep it kind of secretive. Is it possible to do this? If so, how? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: gag.sf.net is probably a great solution for not modifying the initial disk... if you're using an MBR.  I don't think it supports GPT though.  If you're using MBR, you could install it to the hard drive, which may destroy your "secretive" goal, but if you boot off the CD (and then take the CD with you) then that might be an option.  Another option might be changing the BIOS to temporarily disable the hard drive you don't want to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Most computers nowadays have a key to access the boot menu. You have to press this key during the bios stage of boot and it will then give you a choice to which device you want to boot into, skipping the default boot order.

These keys are usually one of the following: ESC or F1 to F12. Due to the lack of information in your post about what computer or motherboard you have, I cannot look up what key would work for you, so you'll have to start experimenting, or refer to the manual of your motherboard.

Do note, the key is often shown at the bios screen. If you only see an image, press ESC to see the bios. The key is often shown there.

Comment: Thank you for that info. The motherboard I have is the Z-97 Extreme3. I have heard of the boot menu and I think that could work. I am not at my computer right now, but I’ll let you know if I figure this out later.

Comment: @AliHegazi sure. Good luck. :)

Comment: So I did everything, but what happens when I press f11 is that it still continues to load off my default windows installation, even when I press on the secondary hard drive. I think this has to do with the windows startup and recovery settings since the default is set to that there. I unchecked the “Time to display list of operating systems” option because as you know, I don’t want that to be seen. I only want it to work from the boot menu on startup when I press F11. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, it happens because the bootloader is altered. The only way I can think of is to unplug the other harddrive when installing windows, so the bootloader does not detect the other windows. But I'm not sure if this technique still applies in windows 10. If all you want to do is hide a 2nd OS, consider using a Virtual Machine. You basically boot in windows first, then whenever you want, you start the Virtual Machine to access the secretive windows.

Comment: The vm sounds like it could be a good idea, but I heard they don’t fully utilize the hardware in your pc. One thing I saw which I think might work is this. https://superuser.com/questions/1158161/desktop-shortcut-for-rebooting-into-different-os

Comment: VM's do fully utilize the hardware in your pc, it simply doesn't expose it fully to the guest but uses its own hardware instead, but it also highly depends on the VM. Hyper-V for example will fully expose the hardware and the guest will think the hardware is installed, but the VM will intercept the requests and passes it through the host. At least most of the time. It depends on what you want to do. Do notice that running a VM is cpu intensive, so gaming is going to be less of a good idea in a VM. the bcdedit, I have no experience with it, and I can't test it, but it sounds like it could work.